Difference (or not) between `*` and `*.*` on _current generation_ Windows
In the days of good old MS-DOS and FAT16, there was no such thing as a file with no extension (any file that appeared to have no extension actually had a blank extension) and therefore *.* was the conventional glob pattern that matched all file names.  * by itself, if memory serves, would match only file names with blank extensions, which would usually only be directories.
Is this still the case on current-generation Windows, with NTFS (which unlike FAT doesn't have an intrinsic concept of file name extensions AFAICT)?  That *.* matches all file names, whether or not they actually contain any dots, and that * matches only file names that don't contain dots?
(For concreteness, today I only need to care about Windows 10 and later, but an ideal answer would consider the complete release history of Windows and report exactly when and under what circumstances the semantics of globs changed, if they ever did.)
To put it in more concrete terms, is there any difference between these two command lines when executed on current Windows
attrib +r src\* /s /d
attrib +r src\*.* /s /d

and, if there is a difference, which of the two will make all files in src read-only?

Do you mean Win11 only? What about 10, server OS? Rather than saying "current generation" could you more precisely list the OS versions you're looking for answers regarding.

@music2myear Clarification added.

it has nothing to do with the filesystem. You can have long filename on FAT so pretty easy to have no-extension files. It's related to the Win32 namespace and the command or shell: Why does dir *.* give me all files and folders?. In cmd it's the same rule as in DOS but in powershell the rule is more modern, and that applies to any filesystems
